# Can not resolve the symbol FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

The Activity shows error while importing the FragmentActivity.

```
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
  import android.text.TextUtils;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DetailActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

My build.gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'android'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.0.2"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.txt'

        }
        }
    }

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile 'com.google.android:support-v4:r7'
}
```

Comment: Post your error

Comment: and your full code.

Comment: did you solve this yet ?

Answer (score 1):

At First

**Remove Unnecessary**

```
compile 'com.google.android:support-v4:r7' // No Need
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild and Do Gradle`** Your Project